# How to write curl into php?

Tags: php, curl

I have this below php script. I wants to add call function using curl.
How to i write curl on my below script?

I am new in programming. I am still learning it goodly. Please check my code and try to help me adding curl.

My script has not error. Just i wants to add php function replace to curl function.

I hope so, you understand. Sorry for my not good English. thanks

My code is here:

```
$url = 'https://web.facebook.com/'.$pageid.'/videos/'.$id.'/';

$context = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.47 Safari/537.36",
    ],
];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

function cleanStr($str)
{
    return html_entity_decode(strip_tags($str), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

function hd_finallink($curl_content)
{

    $regex = '/hd_src_no_ratelimit:"([^"]+)"/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $curl_content, $match)) {
        return $match[1];

    } else {return;}
}

function sd_finallink($curl_content)
{

    $regex = '/sd_src_no_ratelimit:"([^"]+)"/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $curl_content, $match1)) {
        return $match1[1];

    } else {return;}
}


$hdlink = hd_finallink($data);
$sdlink = sd_finallink($data);

if ($sdlink || $hdlink) {

echo '<a href="'.$hdlink.'" download="hd.mp4" class="link">HD Download </a>'; 
echo '<a href="'.$sdlink.'" download="sd.mp4" class="link">SD Download </a>';

} else {

echo 'Download not showing - Please Reload This Page';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before we can do anything with a cURL request, we need to first instantiate an instance of cURL - we can do this by calling the function `curl_init();`

**Sample code for GET request:**

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://testcURL.com/?item1=value&item2=value2',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

**Sample code for POST request:**

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://testcURL.com',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        item1 => 'value',
        item2 => 'value2'
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

[See this link](http://codular.com/curl-with-php)

Comment: how to i replace it to my php. please update your code with full code. thanks

Comment: `$resp=shell_exec('curl -s -d item1=value -d item2=value2 http://testcURL.com');`